# How to stop INFO messages displaying on spark console?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, spark-submit

I'd like to stop various messages that are coming on spark shell.

I tried to edit the `log4j.properties` file in order to stop these message.

Here are the contents of `log4j.properties`

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```

But messages are still getting displayed on the console.

Here are some example messages

```
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20150105151145-b1ba
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 0.0 B.
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 44728 with id = ConnectionManagerId(192.168.100.85,44728)
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor$BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager 192.168.100.85:44728 with 0.0 B RAM
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/01/05 15:11:45 INFO HttpBroadcast: Broadcast server star
```

How do I stop these?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Thanks @AkhlD and @Sachin Janani for suggesting changes in `.conf` file.

Following code solved my issue:

1) Added `import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}` in import section

2) Added following line after creation of spark context object i.e. after `val sc = new SparkContext(conf)`:

```
val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

Comment: Tried this but still getting the logging outputs.

Comment: I like this solution as having no permission to access conf/

Comment: this will change only the log level of the current java process, after Spark has been initialized

Answer (score 199):

Edit your `conf/log4j.properties` file and change the following line:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

to

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
```

Another approach would be to :

Start spark-shell and type in the following:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

You won't see any logs after that.

Other options for Level include: `all`, `debug`, `error`, `fatal`, `info`, `off`, `trace`, `trace_int`, `warn`

[Details about each can be found in the documentation.](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html)

Comment: I think that OFF is too restrictive. WARN or ERROR may fit better here.

Comment: Add that in your projects Main class.

Comment: Great answer. Any way to do the same from PySpark programmatically?

Comment: The programmatic part of this  does not work. Instead see this answer from @cantdutchthis https://stackoverflow.com/a/37836847/1056563

Comment: @AkhlD: I have added these 3 in my code. Still I can see INFO and WARN messages in log

```log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console```

And
```

val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("org.spark-project").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

```

And 

```ssc.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")```

Answer (score 193):

Right after starting `spark-shell` type ;

```
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

you could put this in preload file and use like:

```
spark-shell ... -I preload-file ...
```

In Spark 2.0 (Scala):

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

API Docs : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

For Java:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate();
spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");
```

Comment: How would you set this property in a program?

Comment: This is only avaibale for spark.sql.SparkSession or also avaibale for JavaSparkContext  ??

Comment: Yes, it's available for [JavaSparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#setLogLevel-java.lang.String-). Thanks, @cantdutchthis. This has bothered me for a while.

Comment: This is the only answer which worked for me without created a separate log4j. thanks!

Comment: It works for me, however I'm still getting a couple of messages at the beginning of my test. Any idea?

Comment: In spark 2.3.1, this reduces my messages by half, but I still get lots of INFO

Comment: Nice, For PySpark it's basically the same syntax actually.

Answer (score 90):

## All the methods collected with examples

## Intro

Actually, **there are many ways to do it**.
Some are harder from others, but it is up to you which one suits you best. I will try to showcase them all.

---

## #1 Programatically in your app

Seems to be the easiest, but you will need to recompile your app to change those settings. Personally, I don't like it but it works fine.

#### Example:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
Logger.getLogger("org.spark-project").setLevel(Level.WARN)
```

**You can achieve much more just using `log4j` API.**
Source: [[Log4J Configuration Docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html), Configuration section]

---

## #2 Pass `log4j.properties` during `spark-submit`

**This one is very tricky, but not impossible. And my favorite.**

Log4J during app startup is always looking for and loading `log4j.properties` file from classpath.

**However, when using `spark-submit` Spark Cluster's classpath has precedence over app's classpath! This is why putting this file in your fat-jar will not override the cluster's settings!**

> Add `-Dlog4j.configuration=<location of configuration file>` to
> `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` *(for the driver)* or
> `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` *(for executors)*.
>
> Note that if using a
> file, the `file:` protocol should be explicitly provided, **and the file
> needs to exist locally on all the nodes**.

To satisfy the last condition, you can either upload the file to the location available for the nodes (like `hdfs`) or access it locally with driver if using `deploy-mode client`. Otherwise:

> upload a custom `log4j.properties` using spark-submit, by adding it to
> the `--files` list of files to be uploaded with the application.

Source: [Spark docs, Debugging](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application)

#### Steps:

Example `log4j.properties`:

```
# Blacklist all to warn level
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Whitelist our app to info :)
log4j.logger.com.github.atais=INFO
```

**Executing `spark-submit`, for cluster mode:**

```
spark-submit \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" \
    --files "/absolute/path/to/your/log4j.properties" \
    --class com.github.atais.Main \
    "SparkApp.jar"
```

Note that you must use `--driver-java-options` if using `client` mode. [Spark docs, Runtime env](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment)

**Executing `spark-submit`, for client mode:**

```
spark-submit \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode client \
    --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/absolute/path/to/your/log4j.properties" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" \
    --files "/absolute/path/to/your/log4j.properties" \
    --class com.github.atais.Main \
    "SparkApp.jar"
```

#### Notes:

1. Files uploaded to `spark-cluster` with `--files` will be available at root dir, so there is no need to add any path in `file:log4j.properties`.
2. Files listed in `--files` must be provided with absolute path!
3. `file:` prefix in configuration URI is mandatory.

---

## #3 Edit cluster's `conf/log4j.properties`

This changes **global logging configuration file**.

> update the `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/log4j.properties` file and it will be
> automatically uploaded along with the other configurations.

Source: [Spark docs, Debugging](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application)

To find your `SPARK_CONF_DIR` you can use `spark-shell`:

```
atais@cluster:~$ spark-shell 
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1
      /_/   

scala> System.getenv("SPARK_CONF_DIR")
res0: String = /var/lib/spark/latest/conf
```

Now just edit `/var/lib/spark/latest/conf/log4j.properties` (with example from method #2) and all your apps will share this configuration.

---

## #4 Override configuration directory

If you like the solution #3, but want to customize it per application, you can actually copy `conf` folder, edit it contents and specify as the root configuration during `spark-submit`.

> To specify a different configuration directory other than the default `“SPARK_HOME/conf”`, you can set `SPARK_CONF_DIR`. Spark will use the configuration files (`spark-defaults.conf`, `spark-env.sh`, `log4j.properties`, *etc*) from this directory.

Source: [Spark docs, Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#overriding-configuration-directory)

#### Steps:

1. Copy cluster's `conf` folder (more info, method #3)
2. Edit `log4j.properties` in that folder (example in method #2)
3. Set `SPARK_CONF_DIR` to this folder, before executing `spark-submit`,
   example:

   ```
   export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/absolute/path/to/custom/conf

   spark-submit \
       --master yarn \
       --deploy-mode cluster \
       --class com.github.atais.Main \
       "SparkApp.jar"
   ```

---

## Conclusion

I am not sure if there is any other method, but I hope this covers the topic from A to Z. If not, feel free to ping me in the comments!

Enjoy your way!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It offers much details and sums up a lot more use cases than the others. (Without encouraging to disable the logs.)

Comment: @Atais - You should add below So if you are like me and find that the answers above didn't help, then maybe you too have to remove the '.template' suffix from your log4j conf file and then the above works perfectly!

Comment: Additional note on the programmatic approach- The level has to be set before the SparkContext is created

Comment: @ArunrajNair should not be the case, because logging is a separate feature, not connected to SparkContext.

Answer (score 35):

Use below command to change log level while submitting application using spark-submit or spark-sql:

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:<file path>/log4j.xml" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:<file path>/log4j.xml"
```

Note: replace `<file path>` where `log4j` config file is stored.

**Log4j.properties:**

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, console

# set the log level for these components
log4j.logger.com.test=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.spark-project=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=ERROR
log4j.logger.io.netty=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR

# add a ConsoleAppender to the logger stdout to write to the console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# use a simple message format
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**log4j.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
   <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
    <logger name="org.apache.spark">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.spark-project">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.hadoop">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="io.netty">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>
   <logger name="org">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value ="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Switch to FileAppender in log4j.xml if you want to write logs to file instead of console. `LOG_DIR` is a variable for logs directory which you can supply using `spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-D`.

```html
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${LOG_DIR}"/>
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Another important thing to understand here is, when job is launched in distributed mode ( deploy-mode cluster and master as yarn or mesos) the log4j configuration file should exist on driver and worker nodes (`log4j.configuration=file:<file path>/log4j.xml`) else log4j init will complain-

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or
>   directory)

Hint on solving this problem-

Keep log4j config file in distributed file system(HDFS or mesos) and add  external configuration using [log4j PropertyConfigurator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).
or use [sparkContext addFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#addFile(java.lang.String)) to make it available on each node then use  log4j PropertyConfigurator to reload configuration.

Comment: This is one of the few examples that doesn't clobber all `org` logs that are traditionally from the default logger.

Comment: This works very well, but what is the `Log4j.properties` file for? It doesn't seem to be used. Are you simply documenting the properties set in the XML file?

Comment: You can use either of them.

Comment: I have had success with the above - I use `--files` in the spark-submit command to make log4j.properties available on all nodes.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me and it does not involve any code change. Create a file `Log4.properties` under `main/resources` in case that it does not exist

Comment: FYI , this solution works very well with Spark 2.x  but it does not seem to work with Spark 1.6.x standalone

Comment: This solution like multiple other solutions online, seems to work only when the deploy mode is 'client'. When deployed in 'cluster' mode, it always uses the log4j.properties files from 'SPARK_HOME/conf/', no matter what combinations of the runtime options are tried (Of course, I am talking about the logs displayed in the console or terminal from where application is submitted). However, all these settings seem to get applied for the logs we see in yarn logs, irrespective of deploy-mode.

Answer (score 19):

You set disable the Logs by setting its level to OFF as follows:

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

or edit log file and set log level to off by just changing the following property:

```
log4j.rootCategory=OFF, console
```

Comment: In which file do I set above properties??

Comment: You can add these lines in your Driver program @Vishwas

Comment: I have added same but still logs appears on console

Comment: Have you change the property log4j.rootCategory=OFF. I have tested these at my end and its working fine

Comment: I have made changes as you mentioned. can you please tell me which version of spark you are using??

Comment: I am using spark 1.0 but i think spark 0.9 also has the same settings as they are related to logs

Comment: This makes zero difference for me on Spark 2.3.1

Comment: This does not seem to work with Spark 1.6.x in standalone

Answer (score 15):

I just add this line to all my pyspark scripts on top just below the import statements.

```
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

example header of my pyspark scripts

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as fs
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't stop the 58 lines of INFO messages that appear during the creation of the Spark context.

Comment: Note that this is for Spark 2.x

Comment: Because those messages are written by the Hadoop cluster, and not the spark session

Answer (score 14):

Answers above are correct but didn't exactly help me as there was additional information I required.

I have just setup Spark so the log4j file still had the '.template' suffix and wasn't being read.  I believe that logging then defaults to Spark core logging conf.

So if you are like me and find that the answers above didn't help, then maybe you too have to remove the '.template' suffix from your log4j conf file and then the above works perfectly!

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/disable-log4j-for-spark-shell-td11278.html

Comment: Please check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51554118/2094086
hope you're looking for the same.

Comment: This works well. Just remove the .template from the log4j fle and set log4j.rootCategory=Error, console

Answer (score 6):

Adding the following to the PySpark did the job for me:

```
self.spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

self.spark is the spark session (`self.spark = spark_builder.getOrCreate()`)

Answer (score 5):

In Python/Spark we can do:

```
def quiet_logs( sc ):
  logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
  logger.LogManager.getLogger("org"). setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )
  logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )
```

The after defining Sparkcontaxt 'sc'
call this function by : quiet_logs( sc )

Comment: I'd love to find a programatic way that works without messing with the log4j file -- but when I try that, I still get warnings like  WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 612.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2570 ..., executor 15): TaskKilled (another attem

Answer (score 5):

#### tl;dr

> For Spark Context you may use:
>
> ```
> sc.setLogLevel(<logLevel>)
> ```
>
> where `loglevel` can be ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, OFF, TRACE or
>   WARN.

---

### Details-

Internally, `setLogLevel` calls `org.apache.log4j.Level.toLevel(logLevel)` that it then uses to set using `org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(level)`.

> You may directly set the logging levels to `OFF` using:
>
> ```
> LogManager.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
> ```

You can set up the default logging for Spark shell in `conf/log4j.properties`. Use `conf/log4j.properties.template` as a starting point.

#### Setting Log Levels in Spark Applications

In standalone Spark applications or while in Spark Shell session, use the following:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

Logger.getLogger(classOf[RackResolver]).getLevel
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

#### Disabling logging(in log4j):

Use the following in `conf/log4j.properties` to disable logging completely:

```
log4j.logger.org=OFF
```

---

***Reference: Mastering Spark by Jacek Laskowski.***

Answer (score 5):

Simply add below param to your spark-shell OR spark-submit command

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4jspark.root.logger=WARN,console"
```

Check exact property name (log4jspark.root.logger here) from log4j.properties file.
Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: To set this from the command-line would have be awesome. But this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Simple to do on the command line...

`spark2-submit --driver-java-options="-Droot.logger=ERROR,console"` ..other options..

Comment: what is `spark2-submit` ?

Comment: spark2-submit is used for Spark2.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting idea is to use the RollingAppender as suggested here: http://shzhangji.com/blog/2015/05/31/spark-streaming-logging-configuration/
so that you don't "polute" the console space, but still be able to see the results under $YOUR_LOG_PATH_HERE/${dm.logging.name}.log.

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, rolling

log4j.appender.rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.conversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.rolling.maxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.rolling.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rolling.file=$YOUR_LOG_PATH_HERE/${dm.logging.name}.log
log4j.appender.rolling.encoding=UTF-8
```

Another method that solves the cause is to observe what kind of loggings do you usually have (coming from different modules and dependencies), and set for each the granularity for the logging, while turning "quiet" third party logs that are too verbose:

For instance,

```
    # Silence akka remoting
log4j.logger.Remoting=ERROR
log4j.logger.akka.event.slf4j=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.server=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.anjuke.dm=${dm.logging.level}
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```

Answer (score 2):

for Spark 3.5.0: go to `/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/conf` folder and run

```
cp log4j2.properties.template log4j2.properties
```

Then in the new file modify
`rootLogger.level` from `info` to `warn`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the ability to edit the java code to insert the `.setLogLevel()` statements and you don't want yet more external files to deploy, you can use a brute force way to solve this. Just filter out the INFO lines using grep.

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master local <rest-of-cmd> | grep -v -F "INFO"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Adjust conf/log4j.properties as described by other
   `log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console`
2. Make sure while executing your spark job you pass `--file` flag with log4j.properties file path
3. If it still doesn't work you might have a jar that has log4j.properties that is being called before your new log4j.properties. Remove that log4j.properties from jar (if appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

```
sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")
```

Comment: I did both- removed the .template suffix from log4j.properties and set the level to ERROR, and                  `val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)`   It worked

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the above posts, here is what solved the issue for me.

Spark uses slf4j to bind to loggers. If log4j is not the first binding found, you can edit log4j.properties files all you want, the loggers are not even used. For example, this could be a possible SLF4J output:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/~/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.6/slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/~/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.19/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.19.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]

So here the SimpleLoggerFactory was used, which does not care about log4j settings.

Excluding the slf4j-simple package from my project via

```
<dependency>
        ...
        <exclusions>
            ...
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

resolved the issue, as now the log4j logger binding is used and any setting in log4j.properties is adhered to.
F.Y.I. my log4j properties file contains (besides the normal configuration)

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout
...
log4j.category.org.apache.spark = WARN
log4j.category.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader = FATAL
log4j.additivity.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader=false
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader=OFF
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this work for me. For anyone who use sbt just add "exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic")"

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.
For only ERROR messages to be displayed as `stdout`, `log4j.properties` file may look like:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

> NOTE: Put `log4j.properties` file in `src/main/resources` folder to be
>   effective. 
>   And if `log4j.properties` doesn't exist (meaning `spark` is using `log4j-defaults.properties` file) then you can create it by going to `SPARK_HOME/conf` and then `mv log4j.properties.template log4j.properties` and then proceed with above said changes.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is stuck on this,

nothing of the above worked for me.
I had to remove

```
implementation group: "ch.qos.logback", name: "logback-classic", version: "1.2.3"
implementation group: 'com.typesafe.scala-logging', name: "scala-logging_$scalaVersion", version: '3.9.2'
```

from my build.gradle for the logs to disappear. TLDR: Don't import any other logging frameworks, you should be fine just using `org.apache.log4j.Logger`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of stopping logs completely is:

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
    import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
    import org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender;

    public class SomeClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Appender nullAppender = new NullAppender();
            BasicConfigurator.configure(nullAppender);

            {...more code here...}

        }
    }
```

This worked for me. 
An NullAppender is

> An Appender that ignores log events. (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/NullAppender.html)