# How to log using log4j to local file system inside a Spark application that runs on YARN?

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm building an Apache Spark Streaming application and cannot make it log to a file on the local filesystem **when running it on YARN**. How can achieve this?

I've set `log4.properties` file so that it can successfully write to a log file in `/tmp` directory on the local file system (shown below partially):

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/application.log
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

When I run my Spark application locally by using the following command:

```
spark-submit --class myModule.myClass --master local[2] --deploy-mode client myApp.jar
```

It runs fine and I can see that log messages are written to `/tmp/application.log` on my local file system.

But when I run the same application via YARN, e.g.

```
spark-submit --class myModule.myClass --master yarn-client  --name "myModule" --total-executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1g myApp.jar
```

or

```
spark-submit --class myModule.myClass --master yarn-cluster  --name "myModule" --total-executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1g myApp.jar
```

I cannot see any `/tmp/application.log` on the local file system of the machine that runs YARN.

What am I missing.

Comment: I just pasted your section of log4j.properties and ran it locally similarly to yours but it isn't creating any log file for my /tmp. am I missing something?

Comment: I found this post useful- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-messages-displaying-on-spark-console

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to append to the JVM arguments used when launching your tasks/jobs.

Try editing `conf/spark-defaults.conf` as [described here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-spark-user/201406.mbox/%3CCANx3uAjZ6RsfpcYTXDagvx7NXj4HRx6szJNBH1pm-aGMx54EbA@mail.gmail.com%3E)

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/apps/spark-1.2.0/conf/log4j.properties

spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/apps/spark-1.2.0/conf/log4j.properties
```

Alternatively try editing `conf/spark-env.sh` as [described here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Specifying-Spark-Executor-Java-options-using-Spark-Submit-td15015.html) to add the same JVM argument, although the entries in conf/spark-defaults.conf should work.

If you are still not getting any joy, you can explicitly pass the location of your log4j.properties file on the command line along with your `spark-submit` like this if the file is contained within your JAR file and in the root directory of your classpath

```
spark-submit --class sparky.MyApp --master spark://my.host.com:7077 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-executor.properties" myapp.jar
```

If the file is not on your classpath use the `file:` prefix and full path like this

```
spark-submit ... --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/apps/spark-1.2.0/conf/log4j-executor.properties" ...
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. My log4j.properties file is packaged into the JAR file. My application is a Maven project, and I'm creating single, big, self-contained JAR file that also has the log4j.properties file in it. This works fine when I run Spark locally. Is this (putting the log4j.properties into JAR) not possible when I run Spark on the YARN cluster?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. I'm trying to help simplify the problem by stripping down the configuration you're using. I'm not an expert in Spark. I have a stand alone cluster logging on a windows host.

Comment: @Emre I had a play around with the various settings mentioned in my answer, which led me to re-write it. I got the logging working by editing `spark-defaults.conf`, and then also got it working by using to `spark-submit --conf`. Either one or the other should work (you shouldn't need both)

Comment: Hi, Can the above be used for a log file that is not on the classpath nor contained within the jar?  I've copied the log.properties to the executor and used the command line arg but it tells it it can't be found, thanks

Comment: Yes. The examples above using `=file:/apps/`are referencing an absolute path on disk and not a file on the class path or in the JAR

Comment: @EmreSevinç this will not work. Spark worker app is not your jar, but an application that run Spark code only sent from the driver, see my answer, you must use a static file (in HDFS or any other shared file-system, or via --files Spark directive).

Comment: Many years later... I agree that the best solution is using `spark-submit --files "./log4j.properties" ...` where log4j.properties resides in the directory from where you execute this command. The properties file will be sent to the Driver and Executors

Answer (score 8):

The above options of specifying the log4j.properties using spark.executor.extraJavaOptions, spark.driver.extraJavaOptions would only log it locally and also the log4.properties should be present locally on each node.

As specified in the https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/running-on-yarn.html documentation, you could alternatively upload log4j.properties along with your applicaiton using --files option. This would do yarn aggregate logging on HDFS and you can access the log using the command

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application id>
```

Comment: do you have an example of a log4j.properties file to log to HDFS?

Comment: @Irene This is the only difference to the otherwise regular log4.properties file. **log4j.appender.file_appender.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark.log**

Answer (score 3):

1) To debug how Spark on YARN is interpreting your log4j settings, use `log4j.debug` flag.

2) Spark will create 2 kind of YARN containers, the driver and the worker. So you want to share a file from where you submit the application with all containers (you cant use a file inside the JAR, since this is not the JAR that really run), so you must use the `--files` Spark submit directive (this will share file with all workers).

Like this:

```
spark-submit     
    --class com.X.datahub.djobi.Djobi \
    --files "./log4j.properties" \
    --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.debug=true -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.debug=true -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties " \
    ./target/X-1.0.jar "$@"
```

Where log4j.properties is a project file inside `src/main/resources/config` folder.

I can see in the console:

```
log4j: Trying to find [config/log4j.properties] using context 
classloader org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader@5bb21b69.
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/home/hdfs/djobi/latest/lib/djobi-1.0.jar!/config/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/home/hdfs/djobi/latest/lib/djobi-1.0.jar!/config/log4j.properties
```

So the file is taken in account, you can check on Spark webUI too.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use **PropertyConfigurator** of log4j to define your custom log properties.

Ex.

```
 import com.foo.Bar;

 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

 public class MySparkApp {

   static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySparkApp.class.getName());

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     // Location to property file
     PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[0]);

     logger.info("Entering application.");

     logger.info("Exiting application.");
   }
 }
```

Your properties file shall have the following props,

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/application.log

log4j.appender.file.append=false

log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

EDIT: Updating link to log4j docs. Spark uses log4j 2, not v1.2

Ref : http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Comment: I don't know if this will work on both executor and driver. In the above code, it will probably code configured only for the driver.

Answer (score 1):

In you log4j.properties file, you should also modify the `log4j.rootCategory` from `INFO,console` to `INFO,file`.

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console    
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,file
```

Comment: Hey @Vojtech this will depend on the version you are for the logger ... take a look at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html