# read log4j properties with typesafe config

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, typesafe-config

I made a pretty standard log4j file, I would like to load and use the properties of it, with it being packed inside the application jar.

Using the Properties from java.util I was able to get it working while launching in yarn-client mode, but using typesafe-config, at the moment, the log4j.properties is completely ignored.

This is the log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=log/rule.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout



log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1} %m%n
```

This is how I retrieve the properties. This should be fine, since the other properties are retrieved correctly.

```
val log = LogManager.getRootLogger()
val logCfgProps : Config =  ConfigFactory.load("log4j.properties")
val configLogProps = Option(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("log4j.properties")).fold
{
  log.error("log4j.properties file not retrieved. Application is shutting down")
  ConfigFactory.load()
}
{ resource => ConfigFactory.load(logCfgProps)}
```

And I try to log with

```
log.error("blabla")
```

On the console I get the right logging but it is not written to file.
I tried to add the option --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" myapp.jar suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454080/how-to-log-using-log4j-to-local-file-system-inside-a-spark-application-that-runs) but it does not make any difference.

EDIT

I opened a [new question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237662/log4j-properties-file-bundled-into-jar-in-spark-app-is-ignored) on how to use Property configurator to make it work, I leave this open since it was about using ConfigFactory.

Comment: Could you check the file name in jar? Is it `log4j-executor.properties` or `log4j.properties`? I'm confused because you used two different file names in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code just reads the properties into the `Config` object, but this doesn't affect log4j, which has no idea about Typesafe Config. It should read the properties file and use it on its own. You should:

1. Check that `log4j.properties` is in `src/main/resources` and added to the jar correctly;
2. If it is, but the logging doesn't work, pass `-Dlog4j.debug` in `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` to see what's happening during initialization;
3. You can also use [`PropertyConfigurator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html) explicitly by calling one of its `configure` methods.

Comment: Thank you, I tried all the above to no results, please check my edits