# Spark Streaming Driver and App work files cleanup

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running `spark 2.0.2` and deployed streaming job in `cluster` deploy-mode on a spark standalone cluster. The streaming job works fine but there is an issue with the application's and driver's **stderr** files that are created in the work directory of `SPARK_HOME`. As the streaming is always running, these files only grow in size and I have no clue how to control it.

I have tried the following solutions even though they are not exactly related to the problem in hand but I still tried and didn't work:

1. [Apache Spark does not delete temporary directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093676/apache-spark-does-not-delete-temporary-directories)
2. [How to log using log4j to local file system inside a Spark application that runs on YARN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454080/how-to-log-using-log4j-to-local-file-system-inside-a-spark-application-that-runs)

Can anyone please help me how to limit the size of these files being created?

P.S: I have tried the solution of adding the below line in `conf/spark-env.sh` and restarting the cluster but it didn't work in case of running streaming application.

```
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=60 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=60"
```

**EDIT**:

@YuvalItzchakov I have tried your suggestion but it didn't work. The driver's `stderr` log is as below:

```
Launch Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/mnt/spark2.0.2/conf/:/mnt/spark2.0.2/jars/*" "-Xmx2048M" "-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true" "-Dspark.eventLog.dir=/mnt/spark2.0.2/JobsLogs" "-Dspark.executor.memory=2g" "-Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=2" "-Dspark.io.compression.codec=snappy" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true" "-Dspark.shuffle.compress=true" "-Dspark.app.name=Streamingjob" "-Dspark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=128M" "-Dspark.master=spark://172.16.0.27:7077" "-Dspark.shuffle.spill.compress=true" "-Dspark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" "-Dspark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows=20000" "-Dspark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///mnt/spark2.0.2/sparkjars/log4j.xml" "-Dspark.jars=file:/mnt/spark2.0.2/sparkjars/StreamingJob-assembly-0.1.0.jar" "-Dspark.executor.instances=10" "-Dspark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///mnt/spark2.0.2/sparkjars/log4j.xml" "-Dspark.driver.memory=2g" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10" "-Dspark.eventLog.compress=true" "-Dspark.executor.cores=1" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=true" "-Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=/mnt/spark2.0.2/JobsLogs" "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///mnt/spark2.0.2/sparkjars/log4j.xml" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@172.16.0.29:34475" "/mnt/spark2.0.2/work/driver-20170210124424-0001/StreamingJob-assembly-0.1.0.jar" "Streamingjob"
========================================

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/02/10 12:44:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cassuser
17/02/10 12:44:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cassuser
17/02/10 12:44:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/02/10 12:44:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
```

And my `log4j.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="TRACE"/>
        <param name="File" value="stdout"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="1MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="levelMin" value="ALL" />
            <param name="levelMax" value="OFF" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="stderr" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="WARN"/>
        <param name="File" value="stderr"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="1MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Note that I have removed this root tag from your xml in the answer as it gives some error:

```
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>
```

Comment: You can provide a custom log4j.xml to your workers and master with a rolling file appender.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Can you please tell me how to do that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom `log4j` xml file for that.

First, declare your XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="TRACE"/>
        <param name="File" value="stdout"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="50MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="100"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="levelMin" value="ALL" />
            <param name="levelMax" value="OFF" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="stderr" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="WARN"/>
        <param name="File" value="stderr"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="50MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="100"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Then, when you run your streaming job, you need to pass the `log4j.xml` file to Spark master and workers via `extraJavaOptions`:

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/log4j.xml \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/log4j.xml
```

Note that the path on the master and worker node maybe different, depending on how you deploy your JAR and files to Spark. You said you're using cluster mode so I assume you're manually dispatching the JAR and extra files, but for anyone running this in client mode, you'll need to also add the xml files via the `--files` flag.

Comment: Will try this..!!

Comment: Please see the edited question. I have added the driver `stderr` log.
BTW, this didn't work. Please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

I'm submitting job to Spark using:
    spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --supervise --conf "spark.eventLog.enabled=true" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///mnt/spark2.0.2/sparkjars/log4j.xml" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///mnt/spark2.0.2/sparkjars/log4j.xml" --master spark://172.16.0.27:7077 --class Streamingjob /mnt/spark2.0.2/sparkjars/StreamingJob-assembly-0.1.0.jar

Comment: Any comments..?

Comment: It's not picking up the file. Is it named `log4j.xml`?

Comment: yes it is named `log4j.xml` and it has `-rwxrwxrwx` permission

Comment: @RaviTeja Not from a brief look. I'll be near a working Spark environment on Sunday, I'll give it a try and see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: Can you help me with this issue too please..??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227096/gradual-increase-in-old-generation-heap-memory