# How do we specify driver-java-options -Dlog4j.configuration in SparkSubmitOperator

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to do spark submit from Airflow in Cluster mode, I wanted to specify log4j properties in submit operator

```
task_id='spark_submit_job',
conn_id='spark_default',
files='/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml',
jars='/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar',
java_class='com.xxx.eim.job.SubmitSparkJob',
application='/root/airflow/code/eimdataprocessor.jar',
total_executor_cores='4',
executor_cores='4',
executor_memory='5g',
num_executors='4',
name='airflow-spark-example',
verbose=False,
driver_memory='10g',
application_args=["XXX"],
conf={'master':'yarn',
     'spark.yarn.queue'='priority',
     'spark.app.name'='XXX',
     'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled'='true'},
     'spark.local.dir'='/opt/eim',
     'spark.shuffle.service.enabled'='true',
     'spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup-failures.ignored'='true',
     'spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version'='2'
     },
dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible ways

1. **`Log4J` *properties* as `Spark` *configuration***

   - Basically trying to achieve the same effect as this line in your `spark-submit` command: `--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"`
   - Passed via [`conf` parameter](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py#L93) in `SparkSubmitOperator`
   - Do note that if you are writing a *custom* `operator` to perform `spark-submit` on a *remote* system, passing a [`Log4J` *configuration-file*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457062/3679900) could be challenging
2. **As *Application-Args***

   - Application-args are [appended *as-it-is*](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py#L280) to `spark-submit` command, so make sure you pass them with any *`--prefix`*(es), if needed
   - Passed via [`application_args`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py#L111) in `SparkSubmitOperator`

Comment: Thanks , that helps