# How to set pyspark logging level to debug?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Can anyone help me with the spark configuration needed to set logging level to debug and capture more logs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can set the default spark logging level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608412/how-can-set-the-default-spark-logging-level)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set **`setLogLevel`** property to **`DEBUG`** in sparksession.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('test').getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")

#or

log4j = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(log4j.Level.DEBUG)

#for custom log
log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().info("custom log")
#2020-05-06 13:43:42 INFO  root:? - custom log
```

Comment: Thanks. But i think this line is creating end less console output in my case. The error was around "connection error"

Comment: @user13485171, Could you update the question with steps you are `performing` and `error`?

Comment: I would like to but i can't as that's little confidential
My code looks like 
Setting environment variables
Creating spark session similarly
Then i tried to change log level

So with the new code recreted the issue
I think it's more because of my server settings/permission
I'll take this up with my IT and update you why it happened