# spark-submit, how to specify log4j.properties

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, slf4j

In spark-submit, how to specify log4j.properties ?

Here is my script. I have tried all of combinations and even just use one local node. but looks like the log4j.properties is not loaded, all debug level info was dumped.

```
current_dir=/tmp
DRIVER_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file://${current_dir}/log4j.properties "

spark-submit \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$current_dir/lib/*"  \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.krb5.conf=${current_dir}/config/krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=${current_dir}/config/mssqldriver.conf" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file://${curent_dir}/log4j.properties " \
--class "my.AppMain" \
--files ${current_dir}/log4j.properties \
--master local[1] \
--driver-java-options "$DRIVER_JAVA_OPTIONS" \
--num-executors 4 \
--driver-memory 16g \
--executor-cores 10 \
--executor-memory 6g \
$current_dir/my-app-SNAPSHOT-assembly.jar
```

log4j properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.additivity.org=false

log4j.logger.org=WARN
parquet.hadoop=WARN
log4j.logger.com.barcap.eddi=WARN
log4j.logger.com.barcap.mercury=WARN
log4j.logger.yarn=WARN
log4j.logger.io.netty=WARN
log4j.logger.Remoting=WARN   
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=ERROR

# this disables the table creation logging which is so verbose
log4j.logger.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver=WARN

# this disables pagination nonsense when running in combined mode
log4j.logger.com.barcap.risk.webservice.servlet.PaginationFactory=WARN
```

Comment: You're only specifying `-Dlog4j.configuration` on the executor. Is that intentional?

Comment: I never had much luck with `-Dlog4j.configuration=` on Hadoop. Since "log4j.properties" is the default file name, just try to add the *directory* that contains the file in the driver CLASSPATH, and Log4J will find it. Or even simpler, drop your file in your $SPARK_CONF_DIR along with `spark-default.conf` and friends...

Comment: first try to do this directly, i.e. use a very simply program and do spark-submit --dirver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/username/file.prop" without anything else. It should work. If not, it could be that your code has dependencies on other slf4j implementation and uses that implementation instead (which means it might be taking their properties).

Comment: checkout this-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-info-messages-displaying-on-spark-console/43747948#43747948

Answer (score 19):

Pay attention the Spark worker is not your Java application, so you can't use a log4j.properties file from the class-path.

To understand how Spark on YARN will read a `log4j.properties` file, you can use the `log4j.debug=true` flag:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.debug=true
```

Most of the time, the error is that the file is not found/available from the worker YARN container. There is a very useful Spark directive that allows to share file: `--files`.

```
--files "./log4j.properties"
```

This will make this file available from all your driver/workers. Add Java extra options:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

Et voilà!

```
log4j: Using URL [file:/var/log/ambari-server/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1524817715596_3370/container_e52_1524817715596_3370_01_000002/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
```

Answer (score 17):

## How to pass local `log4j.properties` file

As I see from your script you want to:

1. Pass local `log4j.properties` to executors
2. Use this file for node's configuration.

---

Note two things about `--files` settings:

1. Files uploaded to spark-cluster with `--files` will be available at root dir of executor workspace, so there is no need to add any path in `file:log4j.properties`.
2. Files listed in `--files` must be provided with absolute path!

Fixing your snippet is very easy now:

```
current_dir=/tmp
log4j_setting="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties"

spark-submit \
...
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=${log4j_setting}" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=${log4j_setting}" \
--class "my.AppMain" \
--files ${current_dir}/log4j.properties \
...
$current_dir/my-app-SNAPSHOT-assembly.jar
```

---

## Need more?

If you would like to read about other ways of configuring logging while using `spark-submit`, please visit my other detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55596389/1549135

Comment: log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:log4j.properties]

Answer (score 5):

Just to add, you can directly pass the conf via spark-submit, no need to modify the default conf file

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///export/home/siva/log4j.properties
```

I ran the below command, it worked fine

```
/usr/hdp/latest/spark2/bin/spark-submit --master local[*] --files ~/log4j.properties --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///export/home/siva/log4j.properties ~/SCD/spark-scd-assembly-1.0.jar test_run
```

Note: If you have extra Java options configured in conf file, just append and submit

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy the spark-defaults.conf to a new app-spark-defaults.conf
2. Add -Dlog4j.configuration=file://log4j.properties to the spark.driver.extraJavaOptions in the app-spark-defaults.conf. For example:

   spark.driver.extraJavaOptions   -XXOther_flag -Dlog4j.configuration=file://log4j.properties
3. Run your spark using --properties-file to the new conf file.
   For example :
   spark-submit --properties-file app-spark-defaults.conf --class my.app.class --master yarn --deploy-mode client ~/my-jar.jar

Comment: oh okay.I unable to figure out how to run on yarn cluster

Answer (score 1):

## Solution for spark-on-yarn

for me, **run spark on yarn,just add --files log4j.properties** makes everything ok.
1. make sure the directory where you run spark-submit contains file "log4j.properties".
2. run spark-submit ...  --files log4j.properties

### let's see why this work

1.spark-submit will upload log4j.properties to hdfs like this

```
20/03/31 01:22:51 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home/ssd/homework/shaofengfeng/tmp/firesparkl-1.0/log4j.properties -> hdfs://sandbox/user/homework/.sparkStaging/application_1580522585397_2668/log4j.properties
```

2.when yarn launches containers for driver or executor,yarn will download all files uploaded into node's local file cache, including files under ${spark_home}/jars,${spark_home}/conf and ${hadoop_conf_dir} and files specified by --jars and  --files.
3.before launcher container, yarn export classpath and make soft links like this

```
export CLASSPATH="$PWD:$PWD/__spark_conf__:$PWD/__spark_libs__/*:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*

ln -sf "/var/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/homework/filecache/1484419/log4j.properties" "log4j.properties"
hadoop_shell_errorcode=$?
if [ $hadoop_shell_errorcode -ne 0 ]
then
  exit $hadoop_shell_errorcode
fi
ln -sf "/var/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/homework/filecache/1484440/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar" "apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar"
```

4.after step3, "log4.properties" is already in CLASSPATH, no need for setting
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions or spark.executor.extraJavaOption.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that spark 3.3.0 switched to log4j2.
Which means you have to configure things [differently](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging).

Answer (score -3):

If this is just for a  self-learning project or small development project, There is already a log4j.properties in hadoop_home/conf. Just edit that one, add your own loggers

Comment: In most installations person running the job is not the same person who control the hadoop_home