# spark-submit log4j configuration has no effect in spark context

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

After specifying a configuration file in a `spark-submit` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55596632/9698684):

```
spark-submit \
    --master local \
    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"\
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"\
    --py-files ./dist/src-1.0-py3-none-any.whl\
    --files "/job/log4j.properties"\ # path in docker container
     main.py -input $1 -output $2 -mapper $3 $4 # app args
```

With the dockerized application structure being:

```
job/
|--  entrypoint.sh
|--  log4j.properties
|--  main.py
```

I'm getting the following error:

> log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:/log4j.properties].log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/log4j.properties].

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /log4j.properties (No such file or directory)

It works fine if I set the configuration from the spark context method: `PropertyConfigurator.configure`:

```
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j.Logger
sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("/job/log4j.properties")
Logger = logger.getLogger("MyLogger")
```

That is, all spark `INFO` level logging is silenced, and I only see warnings and error logs, which is what I've set in the configuration file. However, if I just instanciate a logger as (desirable behaviour):

```
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger("MyLogger")
```

It isn't behaving as at it does setting it via `PropertyConfigurator.configure`, which I've set to silence all spark `INFO` level loggings. Any idea on how to use the logging configuration set in the `spark-submit` to control the application's logs?

Using pyspark with a spark version `3.0.1` and python `3.8.0`.

Comment: Try removing `/job/` from the extraJavaOptions. The file isn't mounted in a job folder unless you pass `--files "/job/log4j.properties:/job/log4j.properties"`

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer . Still seems to behave in the same way though

Comment: Have you try to make it `file:///job/log4j.properties`?

Comment: Also, can you show an example of your `log4j.properties`, and how do you know `It doesn't seem to pick up the configuration`?

Comment: The configuration file should work fine. I've tested it directly from the spark context in the application using the method `PropertyConfigurator.configure`, where I've set all spark loggings to WARN or ERROR level, and `MyLogger` to INFO level, which silenced all other loggings. I don't get the same behaviour setting it through the spark-submit @pltc

Comment: I've tried to set both configuration paths to `--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///log4j.properties"` and still the same. I understand that as @OneCricketeer mentioned the `/job/` is unnecessary

Comment: `file:///foo.bar` isn't correct either (for a clustered environment) unless you distributed the same file to every executor and `foo.bar` is at the root. You could try `file:///path/to/foo.bar`, assuming it is a static pre-distributed file, but don't think that's what's wanted here. From my understanding, `files` doesn't work with a local master because there is no data to distribute and no temporary worker directory is allocated. Therefore, you're going to need the full path here

Comment: That did it @OneCricketeer ! Just got it to work specifying the paths as `file:///job/log4j.properties`, and `--files "/job/log4j.properties"`. Feel free to write the comment as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're in a container and using `--master local`, that would limit you to a local filesystem, which you can access from `file://` URI.

`--files` takes relative paths to where the files are located from where you run the command, and adds to the driver/executor classpath, I think

Putting those two pieces of information together, you can specify

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///job/log4j.properties
```

Along with

```
--files "/job/log4j.properties"
```

---

If you were to run this in a clustered environment, however, then the `-Dlog4j.configuration` settings would not be correct