# Dataproc spark cluster - No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a GCP Dataproc spark cluster, and I'm running a Spark (Structured Streaming) program which reads from Kafka, does processing & finally puts data into multiple sinks (Kafka, Mongo).

Dataproc cluster has the 1 master, 3 worker nodes (n1-highmem-16)

I'm getting error - No available nodes reported, error shown below

```
22/08/30 01:56:48 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
22/08/30 01:56:51 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
22/08/30 01:56:54 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
22/08/30 01:56:57 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
22/08/30 01:57:00 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
22/08/30 01:57:03 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
22/08/30 01:57:07 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
22/08/30 01:57:10 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
22/08/30 01:57:13 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocatorNodeHealthTracker: No available nodes reported, please check Resource Manager.
```

Here is the command used to create the Dataproc cluster :

```
TYPE=n1-highmem-16
CNAME=versa-structured-stream-prom
BUCKET=dataproc-spark-logs
REGION=us-east1
ZONE=us-east1-b
IMG_VERSION=2.0-ubuntu18
PROJECT=versa-sml-googl
NUM_WORKER=3


gcloud compute routers nats create dataproc-nat-spark-kafka --nat-all-subnet-ip-ranges --router=dataproc-router --auto-allocate-nat-external-ips --region=us-east1

# in versa-sml-googl
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create $CNAME \
           --enable-component-gateway \
           --bucket $BUCKET \
           --region $REGION \
           --zone $ZONE \
           --no-address --master-machine-type $TYPE \
           --master-boot-disk-size 500 \
           --master-boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
           --num-workers $NUM_WORKER \
           --worker-machine-type $TYPE \
           --worker-boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
           --worker-boot-disk-size 1000 \
           --image-version $IMG_VERSION \
           --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' \
           --project $PROJECT \
           --initialization-actions 'gs://dataproc-spark-configs/pip_install.sh','gs://dataproc-spark-configs/connectors-feb1.sh','gs://dataproc-spark-configs/prometheus.sh' \
           --metadata 'gcs-connector-version=2.0.0' \
           --metadata 'bigquery-connector-version=1.2.0' \
           --properties 'dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable=true,dataproc:job.history.to-gcs.enabled=true,spark:spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true,spark:spark.eventLog.dir=gs://dataproc-spark-logs/joblogs,spark:spark.history.fs.logDirectory=gs://dataproc-spark-logs/joblogs'
```

command to launch the Structured Streaming job:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark main.py \
  --cluster $CLUSTER  \
  --properties ^#^spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2#spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true#spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true#spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=150m#spark.ui.prometheus.enabled=true#spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.prometheus.io/scrape=true#spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.prometheus.io/path=/metrics/executors/prometheus/#spark.kubernetes.driver.annotation.prometheus.io/port=4040#spark.app.name=structuredstreaming-versa\
  --jars=gs://dataproc-spark-jars/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.3.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/isolation-forest_2.4.3_2.12-2.0.8.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-3.0.2.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/bson-4.0.5.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.5.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar \
  --files=gs://kafka-certs/versa-kafka-gke-ca.p12,gs://kafka-certs/syslog-vani-noacl.p12,gs://kafka-certs/alarm-compression-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/appstats-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/insights-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/intfutil-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/reloadpred-chkpoint-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/reloadpred-user.p12,gs://dataproc-spark-configs/metrics.properties,gs://dataproc-spark-configs/params.cfg,gs://kafka-certs/appstat-anomaly-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/appstat-agg-user.p12,gs://kafka-certs/alarmblock-user.p12  \
  --region us-east1 \
  --py-files streams.zip,utils.zip
```

status of the disk space on masternode :

```
karanalang@versa-structured-stream-prom-m:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             52G     0   52G   0% /dev
tmpfs            11G  1.2M   11G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       485G   14G  472G   3% /
tmpfs            52G     0   52G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            52G     0   52G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      303M  303M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-cli/56
/dev/loop1       47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16292
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2538
/dev/sda15      105M  4.4M  100M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs            11G     0   11G   0% /run/user/113
tmpfs            11G     0   11G   0% /run/user/114
tmpfs            11G     0   11G   0% /run/user/116
tmpfs            11G     0   11G   0% /run/user/112
tmpfs            11G     0   11G   0% /run/user/117
/dev/loop3      304M  304M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-cli/62
tmpfs            11G     0   11G   0% /run/user/1008
```

/dev/loop0, /dev/loop1 etc are showing as 100% Use, what kind of data is stored in this ?

I'm trying to understand what is causing the issue .. and how to fix this ?
any ideas on this ?

tia !

Pls note : In terms of volume being processed it is ~4.5 M messages every 10 minutes (syslog messages are received every 10 minutes), and it takes ~2.5 - 3 minutes to process the data.

UPDATE :
Just ran this command

```
karanalang@versa-structured-stream-prom-m:~$ hdfs dfsadmin -report -live -decommissioning
Configured Capacity: 3121327865856 (2.84 TB)
Present Capacity: 306192543744 (285.16 GB)
DFS Remaining: 306034360320 (285.02 GB)
DFS Used: 158183424 (150.86 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.05%
Replicated Blocks:
    Under replicated blocks: 0
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0
    Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
    Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups: 
    Low redundancy block groups: 0
    Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
    Missing block groups: 0
    Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (3):

Name: 10.142.0.23:9866 (versa-structured-stream-prom-w-0.c.versa-sml-googl.internal)
Hostname: versa-structured-stream-prom-w-0.c.versa-sml-googl.internal
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1040442621952 (968.99 GB)
DFS Used: 7831552 (7.47 MB)
Non DFS Used: 937229017088 (872.86 GB)
DFS Remaining: 103188996096 (96.10 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 9.92%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 2
Last contact: Tue Aug 30 05:36:06 UTC 2022
Last Block Report: Tue Aug 30 01:14:56 UTC 2022
Num of Blocks: 26


Name: 10.142.0.36:9866 (versa-structured-stream-prom-w-1.c.versa-sml-googl.internal)
Hostname: versa-structured-stream-prom-w-1.c.versa-sml-googl.internal
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1040442621952 (968.99 GB)
DFS Used: 72830976 (69.46 MB)
Non DFS Used: 941126131712 (876.49 GB)
DFS Remaining: 99226882048 (92.41 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
DFS Remaining%: 9.54%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 2
Last contact: Tue Aug 30 05:36:07 UTC 2022
Last Block Report: Tue Aug 30 04:21:31 UTC 2022
Num of Blocks: 26


Name: 10.142.0.8:9866 (versa-structured-stream-prom-w-2.c.versa-sml-googl.internal)
Hostname: versa-structured-stream-prom-w-2.c.versa-sml-googl.internal
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 1040442621952 (968.99 GB)
DFS Used: 77520896 (73.93 MB)
Non DFS Used: 936729841664 (872.40 GB)
DFS Remaining: 103618482176 (96.50 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
DFS Remaining%: 9.96%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 2
Last contact: Tue Aug 30 05:36:07 UTC 2022
Last Block Report: Tue Aug 30 02:26:52 UTC 2022
Num of Blocks: 30


Decommissioning datanodes (0):
```

the worker nodes show ->
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%

Also, almost all the 1000GB is used up, is this what is causing the issue ?
Why is the cache not getting free'd up ?

Also, when i run the following command :

```
curl "http://${HOSTNAME}:8088/ws/v1/cluster/nodes"
```

I see this error :

```
"healthReport":"1/1 local-dirs usable space is below configured utilization percentage/no more usable space [ /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir : used space above threshold of 90.0% ] ; 1/1 log-dirs usable space is below configured utilization percentage/no more usable space [ /var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs : used space above threshold of 90.0% ]
```

Question is - What is causing the issue, and how do i fix this ?

UPDATE :
Error i see in the yarn logs :

```
karanalang@versa-structured-stream-w-0:~$ yarn logs -applicationId application_1662411638799_0005 -log_files stderr --size -100
2022-09-05 22:28:02,123 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at versa-structured-stream-m/10.142.0.103:8032
2022-09-05 22:28:02,543 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at versa-structured-stream-m/10.142.0.103:10200
Container: container_1662411638799_0005_01_000002 on versa-structured-stream-w-2.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 05 22:28:03 +0000 2022
LogLength:68980134141
LogContents:
rruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
End of LogType:stderr.This log file belongs to a running container (container_1662411638799_0005_01_000002) and so may not be complete.
***********************************************************************


Container: container_1662411638799_0005_01_000003 on versa-structured-stream-w-1.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 05 21:37:08 +0000 2022
LogLength:636166940
LogContents:
2/09/05 21:37:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
End of LogType:stderr.
***********************************************************************


Container: container_1662411638799_0005_01_000001 on versa-structured-stream-w-0.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 05 22:23:34 +0000 2022
LogLength:82194130445
LogContents:
cutor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 425.0 (TID 1847): Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
End of LogType:stderr.
***********************************************************************


karanalang@versa-structured-stream-w-0:~$ yarn logs -applicationId application_1662411638799_0005 -log_files stderr --size -300
2022-09-05 22:28:22,626 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at versa-structured-stream-m/10.142.0.103:8032
2022-09-05 22:28:23,053 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at versa-structured-stream-m/10.142.0.103:10200
Container: container_1662411638799_0005_01_000002 on versa-structured-stream-w-2.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 05 22:28:23 +0000 2022
LogLength:70328318158
LogContents:
ets=21143', ' mstatsTotRecvdOctets=22546', ' mstatsTotSessDuration=300000', '22/09/05 22:28:23 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
End of LogType:stderr.This log file belongs to a running container (container_1662411638799_0005_01_000002) and so may not be complete.
***********************************************************************


Container: container_1662411638799_0005_01_000003 on versa-structured-stream-w-1.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 05 21:37:08 +0000 2022
LogLength:636166940
LogContents:
c1da28e-594190416-executor-3, groupId=spark-kafka-source-a72e590c-84a9-4f54-850f-9c00fc1da28e-594190416-executor] Resetting offset for partition syslog.ueba-us4.v1.versa.demo3-2 to offset 340737332.
22/09/05 21:37:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
End of LogType:stderr.
***********************************************************************


Container: container_1662411638799_0005_01_000001 on versa-structured-stream-w-0.c.versa-sml-googl.internal:8026
LogAggregationType: LOCAL
================================================================================================================
LogType:stderr
LogLastModifiedTime:Mon Sep 05 22:23:34 +0000 2022
LogLength:82194130445
LogContents:
scala:232)
22/09/05 22:23:34 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 425.0 (TID 1845): Broken pipe (Write failed)
22/09/05 22:23:34 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 425.0 (TID 1847): Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
End of LogType:stderr.
***********************************************************************
```

Per note from @Dagang,
the /var/log/hadoop-yarn/userlogs/containerId/stderr is filling up fast, primarily couple of errors I see in stderr

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Buffer overflow when available data size (16384) >= application buffer size (16384)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:597)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:544)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:227)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.position(KafkaConsumer.java:1760)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.position(KafkaConsumer.java:1718)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumer.getAvailableOffsetRange(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumer.fetch(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.fetchData(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:539)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.fetchRecord(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.$anonfun$get$1(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.runUninterruptiblyIfPossible(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchPartitionReader.next(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.PartitionIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MetricsIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

2nd error (actually a warning), probably related to pyspark UDFs ?

```
 when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
22/09/06 00:34:17 WARN org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer: KafkaDataConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when KafkaDataConsumer's methods are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894
```

Comment: Can you try increasing the disk size of the worker nodes?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT - i've increased the disk size(as a temporary measure), however - any ideas on what is causing the disk to be filled up (eg. shuffle, debug statements etc)

Comment: @OneCricketeer - any ideas on this ?

Comment: The problem seems to be that there are too many non-HDFS local files on worker nodes, causing YARN NodeManagers to go into unhealthy state. You can SSH into workers and check what files are consuming space. I guess they are tmp data (e.g., shuffle data). You can also check Spark UI to see how much shuffle data it is generating. You need to make sure you provision sufficient disk space for your workload.

Comment: @Dagang - I've updated the yarn logs in the desription, the issue does not seem to be because of shuffle, the max shuffle read, shuffle write s going up to 15-25 GB, and i have 1000GB pd-ssd allocated.

Comment: This is the error i see frequently : 22/09/05 21:37:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
End of LogType:stderr.
***********************************************************************
I've updated the description as well

Comment: Have you SSHed into a worker node and run `du` to figure out what's taking up the space?

Comment: @Dagang - yes, i did login to the VM & the persistent disk is filling up .. specifically /var/log/  is filling up (stderr is increasing and occupying major part of the space) .. I've updated the description with details

Comment: Do you know which log is taking up the space? I don't see the details in the description.

Comment: @Dagang - just updated the description

Comment: Seems these errors / warnings are related to your application or its dependencies. I did a search and found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8154 for the error. If you'd like to suppress the error log you can add a custom log4j config when submitting the job, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230235/spark-submit-how-to-specify-log4j-properties

Comment: @Dagang - thnx, yes i was referring to the same jira, will check and update on my findings on this

Comment: Hi @KaranAlang, Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT - i've resolved the specific issue wrt issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8154 , however the issue of stderr filling up over a period time, and causing the 'No available nodes reported' still exists

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.