# How to use a specific log4j2.properties file in my Spark application / driver?

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to use a custom `log4j2.properties` file in my Spark app (and also in the driver)

My Spark version is up to date : `3.5.0`

I followed the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230235/spark-submit-how-to-specify-log4j-properties), adapting it to log4j2

So basically I added this to `spark-submit`

```
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.properties'
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.properties'
--files 'path/to/log4j2.properties'
```

In driver logs, I can see the JVM argument : `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.properties`

But the weird thing is that in logs (stderr), I can see that :

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
[...]
23/09/29 14:04:08 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:///path/to/log4j2.properties at spark://server:port/files/log4j2.properties with timestamp 1695989047843
```

The `log4j2.properties` file is copied **after** the logger is initialized so as a consequence, it does not work, my file is not taken into account. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. (Spark version: `3.3.0`)

It seems that `Dlog4j.configuration` is an older version of `Dlog4j2.configurationFile` and the following syntax worked for me:

```
--files "./shared/code/log4j.properties" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:./shared/code/log4j.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:./shared/code/log4j.properties" \
```

`shared` is a mounted folder in the docker container where I am running the spark cluster in client mode.