# No Space left on device on spark cluster nodes in stdout folder

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running my spark job on 4 nodes cluster, after some time i keep getting error that "No space left on device".

i checked the nodes **du -h -s *** command and it shows stdout folder as full.

```
$$ du -h -s *
   4.0K logs
   4.0K stderr
   25G  stdout
```

As you can see stdout folder is full, How can i stop it. How can i tell my cluster to stop writing debug and info logs to stdout?

Comment: i think the question is duplicated, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-messages-displaying-on-spark-console