# How to set scala breeze logger

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, netlib-java

The performance session at the bottom of [page](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet) says that "Set your logger settings to ALL for the com.github.fommil.netlib package to check the status, and to com.github.fommil.jniloader for a more detailed breakdown. "

I am running some linear algebra code on Spark using Breeze. I added

```
log4j.logger.com.github.fommil.netlib=ALL
log4j.logger.com.github.fommil.jniloader=ALL
```

to the `log4j.properties` file at `spark-2.1.0/conf`. But I fail to see any logging information regarding netlib-java.

Comment: have you tried to supply log4j properties while starting app? like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-messages-displaying-on-spark-console)

Comment: yes, the two lines mentioned in the post are added to the log4j.properties file.

Comment: can you add command to post? if using cluster mode then the logs will be available on respective driver/executor node log file.

Comment: It is just a normal spark-submit command using local[1] as master, I can see logs for other classes but not the ones for netlib.