# how to silence specific logs in spark log4j

Tags: apache-spark, logging, log4j

How can I specifically silence the following logs in sparks `log4j.properties`?

```
17/12/20 07:39:56 INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
17/12/20 07:39:56 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
17/12/20 07:39:58 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/12/20 07:39:58 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/12/20 07:39:58 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/12/20 07:39:58 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/12/20 07:39:58 INFO Query: Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
17/12/20 07:39:59 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
```

I already set:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive=WARN
```

but that does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop messages displaying on spark console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-messages-displaying-on-spark-console)

Comment: Similar. But setting it all to error is not optimal

Comment: This is not a dupe.