# Disable INFO messages in Spark for an specific application

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

I've tried to disable INFO messages in Spark in a particular application, but I couldn't, I was still seeing it.

The code I tried was from here: ([How to stop messages displaying on spark console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-messages-displaying-on-spark-console) )

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)`
```

I've also edited the log4j file in Spark installation dir, putting this:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
```

And it worked! But it is not the solution that I wanted... I would like to disable the INFO message from each application.

Any comments? Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

**before** creating a **SparkContext**.
Do something like this:

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Also, you can use `getRootLogger` method:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right, both ways worked! Just, please edit the code after "Do something like this:"  putting val sc... line at the end, as you said :)

Comment: Yes, that's my bad) Thanks.

Comment: Is there a similar way to disable logging in pyspark before creating a SparkContext?