# Changing logging level of spark in Scala using log4j2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j2

I am using Scala to do some Spark job (my spark version is 2.1 running on Amazon AWS)

To be able to use log4j2 I have added this to my `POM.XML`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--log4j-api and log4j-core versions should be 2.8.2 it's not working for higher version at this moment-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I have this `log4j2.xml` in my `resources`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}t [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I want to change the level of the log for Spark to `WARN` because of this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21718), but since spark using log4j (version 1 ) I can not control it in my `log4j2.xm`l file. Any workaround?

I have also followed other solution by adding following code but still, it didn't work

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, LogManager, Logger}

val ss = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
ss.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
LogManager.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN)
```

Comment: Sure nothing useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-messages-displaying-on-spark-console)?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have read that before posting this, none of them worked for me