# How to ignore spark-submit warnings for pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, warnings, spark-submit

When I submit my python file to spark like this

```
spark-submit driver.py
```

It starts showing a lot of warning related to python 2 print method.

```
18/10/19 01:37:52 WARN ScriptBasedMapping: Exception running /etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py 10.5.1.112
ExitCodeException exitCode=1:   File "/etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py", line 63
    print rack
             ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(rack)?
```

Is there any way like `spark-submit driver.py -W ignore` ??

**>>** I know this is the warning of python2, my code is in python3 so I just want to ignore the python2 warnings. These warnings start showing even before control goes to my code. Because `spark-submit` runs first and later on load python files.

Answer (score 4):

You're using python 3, but writing in Python 2?

Please refer to this question : [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

You can also refer to [Configure logging in Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging) to set the default loglevel using a log4j.properties file.

You can also set the loglevel when you call `spark-submit` or inside the code using `sc.setLogLevel("WARN")`

Just another SO question for reference : [How to stop INFO messages displaying on spark console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-info-messages-displaying-on-spark-console)

Comment: I am using python 3, Problem is `spark-submit` runs first and generates the warning. You can see it is complaining `/etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py` which is hadoop file, My code is `driver.py`

Comment: @Avinash Please close the question if you have your answer