# how to ignore imported libraries log when using log4j in spark applications

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, spark-graphx

I am doing a project with spark graphx.
i want to log on my codes for tracing, ...
i use the below codes for creating logger object.

```
package org.araz.DAF.GraphAnalysis
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.araz.DAF.{GEdge, GVertex}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
class GraphAnalysis(_graph: Graph[GVertex, GEdge]) {
  var graph: Graph[GVertex, GEdge] = _graph
  def GetConnectedComponents(_cnt: Int): Array[ConnectedComponents] = {
    val logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
    val cc = graph.connectedComponents()
    logger.info("Info 1")
    cc
  }
}
```

when i open the log file, i found more lines rather than "Info 1", more lines of graphx library. spark inner logs.
how can i log only my logs and ignore outer libraries log

Comment: Did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781187/how-to-stop-info-messages-displaying-on-spark-console ?

Comment: thanks 4 you comment. but that link ignores WARN logs if i log from WARN type. so my logs missed.

Answer (score 0):

Update Log4j properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR
...
...
...
log4j.logger.org.araz.DAF.GraphAnalysis=INFO
```

Easiest way to stop printing spark logs could be:

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)// OFF
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)//OFF
```